# fullcalendar move event in min/max time

Tags: jquery, html

I use in my project [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) time management employee. I have a problem with moving event in agendaView. When I set minTime: '09:00:00' and maxTime: '17:00:00' and I move event over minTime, I want to the event moved to an earlier day. Unfortunately this is not happening, but uses the 24-hour time

Example:

My event: 10:00-12:00

Move over 9:00 event about an hour and i want to see the event from 16:00-17:00 prior day and from 9:00-10:00 the next day.

Has anyone an idea how to fix it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.css"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.print.css " media="print">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: ',month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
defaultView: 'agendaDay',
minTime: '09:00:00',
maxTime: '17:00:00',
editable: true,


events: [
    {
        resourceId: '8',
        title:  'My Event',
        start:  '2017-03-16T10:00:00',
        //duration: '00:20:00',
        end: '2017-03-16T12:00:00',
        allDay: false
    }
]


});
</script>
```

Comment: what you want isn't the default behaviour of the calendar. You'll have to write some custom code to check the time the event has been moved to, and amend it to where you want it to go. What have you tried so far? All that's shown here is the most basic calendar setup.

Comment: I understand that this is default behaviour, but I need a solution. I need a solution on how to do it. Do you want to change the full calendar for something else or write from scratch yourself?

Comment: well, this isn't a free coding service - you're expected to show some effort and try to make a solution, then ask when it doesn't work. People generally don't code the entire solution for you from nothing. My suggestion would be to look at the eventDrop callback - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/ - the moved event is passed into the callback, so you can check if the start/end times are valid, and if not, move the event again to an acceptable location.

Comment: I understand that this is not for free. I thought that someone has already found a problem and help me solve it. I don't expect that someone will be it for me wrote